# Airflow DAG Scheduled date is a week behind

Tags: python, airflow

I have a DAG scheduled to run at `10AM` every Monday. Here is my dag definition

```
DAG = models.DAG(
  dag_id="etl", schedule_interval="0 10 * * 1", start_date=datetime(2018, 10, 1), 
  default_args=args
)

latest_only = LatestOnlyOperator(task_id="latest", dag=DAG)

extract = PythonOperator(
task_id="extract", python_callable=extract,  dag=DAG)

extract.set_upstream(latest_only)
```

It gets triggered at `10AM` every Monday. It ran today(05/06/2019) but it has scheduled date as `2019-04-29 14:00:00`
The task instance has the following date

```
execution_date : 2019-04-29T14:00:00+00:00
start_date : 2019-05-06 14:19:48.527488+00:00
end_date : 2019-05-06 14:19:54.225001+00:00
```

It ran fine last Monday (4/29) with the right dates and in the dag history it now shows 2 runs on 4/29. What could be causing this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's a [chapter on Scheduling in the Airflow documentation](https://airflow.apache.org/scheduler.html#scheduling-triggers), which states:

> Note that if you run a DAG on a schedule_interval of one day, the run stamped 2016-01-01 will be trigger soon after 2016-01-01T23:59. In other words, the job instance is started once the period it covers has ended.
>
> **Let’s Repeat That** The scheduler runs your job one schedule_interval AFTER the start date, at the END of the period.

You are experiencing exactly this: today (2019-05-06) a DagRun is created for the latest "completed" interval, meaning the week starting on 2019-04-29.

Thinking about it like this might help: if you want to process some data periodically, you need to start processing it *after* the data is ready for that period.

Answer (score 4):

Airflow schedule a dag at the ending of each interval with execution time as the starting of that interval. So usually **execution_time=schedule_time-interval**.

For example, in your dag, the last interval was 2019-04-29T14:00:00 to 2019-05-06T14:00:00 and its execution only get scheduled on 2019-05-06T14:00:00 with execution time as 2019-04-29T14:00:00. It is the usual working of airflow. It's not sure how your dag did run with 2019-04-29T14:00:00 before MAY 6th 2 PM, as you mentioned in your question. Maybe you changed the dag interval or made a manual trigger.